# How can I see me expensive methods in PerfView

Tags: performance, .net-4.0, perfview

I have created a simple console app and execute it from PerfView via Run Command -> PerfMonTest.exe

I get the log file and see the process of the app. It is expensive as expected (99% CPU ), but when I want to drill down into the expensive methods they are not shown in the list of expensive methods.

Is there something I can do to make them visible?

Here is the view when I selected the process. I would expect CallExpensive and CallCheap in the list:

[image]

Selecting the Main Methods doesnt give me the chace to drill further into the called methods

[image]

Here is the app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace PerfMonTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 2000; i++)
            {
                CallExpensive(1000);
                CallCheap(1000);
                CallCheap(400);
            }

        }

        public static void CallExpensive(int expense)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= expense; i++)
            {
                DateTime checkTime = DateTime.Now;
                string val = "10" + i.ToString();
            }
        }

        public static void CallCheap(int expense)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= expense; i++)
            {
                int j = 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the screenshots it looks like, you didn't load symbols. If you do, you'll see that most of the time is spent in `DateTime.Now`.

If you click on `Main` in the *By Name* view, you'll go to the *Callers* view, which will tell you which methods called `Main`. If you want to drill into what methods `Main` is calling, you need to go to the *Callees* view. If you do that, you'll see the break down of what `Main` calls.

However, in this particular case the logic of `CallExpensive` and `CallCheap` is so simple, that the methods will be inlined (in release mode). Because the methods are inlined, they don't appear as part of the calls made from `Main` as the code has been folded into `Main` itself.

You can verify that the methods are inlined by attaching a debugger after the methods have run and look at the method descriptors for the type. Here's the output I got:

```
0:004> !dumpmt -md 004737c0
EEClass:         00471278
Module:          00472e94
Name:            ConsoleApplication1.Program
mdToken:         02000002
File:            C:\temp\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Release\ConsoleApplication1.exe
BaseSize:        0xc
ComponentSize:   0x0
Slots in VTable: 8
Number of IFaces in IFaceMap: 0
--------------------------------------
MethodDesc Table
   Entry MethodDe    JIT Name
72064a00 71d66728 PreJIT System.Object.ToString()
72058830 71d66730 PreJIT System.Object.Equals(System.Object)
72058400 71d66750 PreJIT System.Object.GetHashCode()
72051790 71d66764 PreJIT System.Object.Finalize()
0047c01d 004737b8   NONE ConsoleApplication1.Program..ctor()
004d0050 00473794    JIT ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(System.String[])
0047c015 004737a0   NONE ConsoleApplication1.Program.CallExpensive(Int32)
0047c019 004737ac   NONE ConsoleApplication1.Program.CallCheap(Int32)
```

The fact that `CallExpensive` and `CallCheap` have `NONE` listed in the JIT column indicates that they were inlined (or not called at all, but that's not the case here).

Comment: I compiled the application in debug mode and CallExpensive is now visible.