# Is the .NET stress log useful to troubleshoot apparent application slowdown?

Tags: .net, performance, debugging

So, I enabled .NET stress log as described in the help of the sos DumpLog command. I gave log level 10 to collect maximum information.

Now that I have this log I am wondering what is it good for? I dumped it into an SQL Server table, so I can conveniently query it. However, I have no idea what to query.

My question is this - has anyone actually used it to troubleshoot .NET application slowdown and found it useful? I.e. it helped to locate the cause of the slowdown?

This is related to my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847263/how-to-troubleshoot-apparent-slowdown-of-a-net-process-hosted-in-iis).

Comment: Application slowdown - I would start from using one of the performance profilers like Ants Performance Profiler or dotTrace.

Comment: I would too, normally. However, the slowdown occurs after the process has run for some time or done some amount of work. For instance, ran 2000 reports. There is no chance we can reach there when running under profiler.

Comment: I see. Then I would use PerfView at the moment of the slowdown. Look at at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828491/how-can-i-see-me-expensive-methods-in-perfview)

Comment: Thanks. I am going to talk with my superior about it.

Comment: Very good, we used PerfView and it helped us to identify the cause - turns out the Activator.CreateInstance takes 28% of the time whereas it is invisible normally.

Comment: I have just created http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146405/the-gradual-degradation-of-activator-createinstance-performance to describe our situation