# A case of abysmal degradation of Activator.CreateInstance performance

Tags: .net, performance, .net-4.5

There is an interesting behavior that we are observing in our .NET server side application.

The CPU/Memory bound work slows down with time. We used PerfView to try and locate the culprit and it seems that `Activator.CreateInstance` is the one.

How did we find it? We ran the same job at the beginning of a fresh session and following execution of about 3,000 reports. In the first case, PerfView did not even show `Activator.CreateInstance` - its percentage was too close to 0% (but rest assured it was called). For the second case, it showed 28%.

So, what is the deal with `Activator.CreateInstance`?

We are using .NET 4.5

**EDIT**

We are using the default construction version of `Activator.CreateInstance`.

**EDIT 2**

An important development. We have managed to narrow the case to the usage of the Microsoft reporting framework in conjunction with enabling `NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy`.

In fact, we have a small test case calling `Activator.CreateInstance` before and after generating a tiny report. Please, find below the output:

```
new() = 4, Activator.CreateInstance() = 38
Building one report ... done.
new() = 13, Activator.CreateInstance() = 2261
```

What it means is that calling `Activator.CreateInstance()` 500,000 times before the report was generated took only 38 milliseconds. **After the tiny report it took 59 times more**!

Here is the entire code:

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;

namespace CreateInstanceTest
{
    internal class TestClass
    {
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            const int COUNT = 500000;
            long newTime;
            long createInstanceTime;

            DoOneRound(COUNT, out newTime, out createInstanceTime);
            Console.WriteLine("new() = {0}, Activator.CreateInstance() = {1}", newTime, createInstanceTime);

            Console.Write("Building one report ... ");
            Console.Out.Flush();
            RunReport();
            Console.WriteLine("done.");

            DoOneRound(COUNT, out newTime, out createInstanceTime);
            Console.WriteLine("new() = {0}, Activator.CreateInstance() = {1}", newTime, createInstanceTime);

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to terminate ...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void DoOneRound(int count, out long newTime, out long createInstanceTime)
        {
            var sw = new Stopwatch();

            sw.Start();
            for (int index = 0; index < count; ++index)
            {
// ReSharper disable ObjectCreationAsStatement
                new TestClass();
// ReSharper restore ObjectCreationAsStatement
            }
            sw.Stop();
            newTime = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            var type = typeof(TestClass);
            sw.Restart();
            for (int index = 0; index < count; ++index)
            {
                Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            }
            sw.Stop();
            createInstanceTime = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        }

        private static void RunReport()
        {
            var localReport = new LocalReport();
            localReport.LoadReportDefinition(new StringReader(
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"+
                    "<Report xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition\">"+
                    "  <Body>"+
                    "    <Height>1in</Height>"+
                    "  </Body>"+
                    "  <Width>1in</Width>"+
                    "  <Page>"+
                    "    <PageFooter>"+
                    "      <Height>1in</Height>"+
                    "      <ReportItems>"+
                    "        <Textbox Name=\"OverallTotalPages\">"+
                    "          <Paragraphs>"+
                    "            <Paragraph>"+
                    "              <TextRuns>"+
                    "                <TextRun>"+
                    "                  <Value>=Globals!OverallTotalPages</Value>"+
                    "                </TextRun>"+
                    "              </TextRuns>"+
                    "            </Paragraph>"+
                    "          </Paragraphs>"+
                    "        </Textbox>"+
                    "      </ReportItems>"+
                    "    </PageFooter>"+
                    "  </Page>"+
                    "</Report>"
                ));
            localReport.Render("pdf");
       }
    }
}
```

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

**CreateInstanceTest.csproj**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{83690315-C8AC-4C52-9CDD-334115F521C0}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>CreateInstanceTest</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>CreateInstanceTest</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Note, that disabling `NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy` in the config file does miracles:

```
new() = 7, Activator.CreateInstance() = 106
Building one report ... done.
new() = 7, Activator.CreateInstance() = 78
```

Unfortunately, we are stuck with `NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy` for other reasons, so disabling it is not an option.

Any input is most welcome.

**EDIT 3**

[How to make Activator.CreateInstance run about 20 times slower with a completely empty type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21191291/how-to-make-activator-createinstance-run-about-20-times-slower-with-a-completely)

Comment: Just to make sure: does the time shown by PerfView include the time taken by the type's constructor? If so, have you checked whether the type's constructor does anything (for example, looking up data in an ever-growing list) that starts taking longer and longer?

Comment: If that was the case, then `Exc%` and `Inc%` would have been different, right? Well they are exactly the same. But we are looking into the types being created right now. Though most of them should just be DTOs with empty constructors.

Comment: In theory, it would still be possible if the constructor gets inlined, but I agree that that looks very unlikely.