# How to make Activator.CreateInstance run about 20 times slower with a completely empty type

Tags: .net

Given:

- .NET assembly named `expression_host`
- .NET assembly named `CreateInstanceTest`
- CreateInstanceTest enables NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy in its config file
- expression_host is attributed with `SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.RequestOptional)`
- CreateInstanceTest loads the expression_host assembly - **bang!!!** - `Activator.CreateInstance` is toast

Please, observe the output:

```
new() = 13, Activator.CreateInstance() = 111
Just loaded expression_host, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
new() = 6, Activator.CreateInstance() = 1944
```

Explanation:

1. The program does 500,000 times `new TestClass()` and 500,000 times `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TestClass))`
2. Then it loads the expression_host assembly
3. Then it repeats the step 1.
4. The numbers are milliseconds.

Both assemblies are really small. Here is the code:

**CreateInstanceTest**

**CreateInstanceTest.csproj**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{83690315-C8AC-4C52-9CDD-334115F521C0}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>CreateInstanceTest</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>CreateInstanceTest</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Users\mkharitonov\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CreateInstanceTest\expression_host\expression_host.csproj">
      <Project>{01f4b604-d5a3-454f-aff7-e1f5c43d293e}</Project>
      <Name>expression_host</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

**Program.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace CreateInstanceTest
{
    internal class TestClass
    {
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            const int COUNT = 500000;
            long newTime;
            long createInstanceTime;

            DoOneRound(COUNT, out newTime, out createInstanceTime);
            Console.WriteLine("new() = {0}, Activator.CreateInstance() = {1}", newTime, createInstanceTime);

            ScrewThingsUp();

            DoOneRound(COUNT, out newTime, out createInstanceTime);
            Console.WriteLine("new() = {0}, Activator.CreateInstance() = {1}", newTime, createInstanceTime);

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to terminate ...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void DoOneRound(int count, out long newTime, out long createInstanceTime)
        {
            var sw = new Stopwatch();

            sw.Start();
            for (int index = 0; index < count; ++index)
            {
// ReSharper disable ObjectCreationAsStatement
                new TestClass();
// ReSharper restore ObjectCreationAsStatement
            }
            sw.Stop();
            newTime = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            var type = typeof(TestClass);
            sw.Restart();
            for (int index = 0; index < count; ++index)
            {
                Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            }
            sw.Stop();
            createInstanceTime = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        }

        private static void ScrewThingsUp()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Just loaded {0}", typeof(ReportExprHostImpl).Assembly.FullName);
       }
    }
}
```

**app.config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

**expression_host**

**expression_host.csproj**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{01F4B604-D5A3-454F-AFF7-E1F5C43D293E}</ProjectGuid>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <AssemblyName>expression_host</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU'">
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="ReportExprHostImpl.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**ReportExprHostImpl.cs**:

```
using System.Security.Permissions;

[assembly: SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.RequestOptional)]
public class ReportExprHostImpl
{
}
```

That's it.

Now what is the question? The question is how to deal with it. This is actually the most minimal reproduction of a real life case and is related to [A case of abysmal degradation of Activator.CreateInstance performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146405/a-case-of-abysmal-degradation-of-activator-createinstance-performance)

In the real application we have to run reports and we are stuck with `NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy`, which makes certain parts of our application perform terrible.

Finally, in the real application we cannot change the code of the expression host assemblies, because these are built dynamically by the Microsoft reporting framework.

So what can we do?

**EDIT**

Adding `[assembly: SecurityTransparent]` to the CreateInstanceTest assembly seems to improve things:

```
new() = 6, Activator.CreateInstance() = 106
Just loaded expression_host, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
new() = 14, Activator.CreateInstance() = 904
```

Now `Activator.CreateInstance` is only about 9 times slower, rather than 20. But still, 9 times slower!

**EDIT 2**

This seems to be an internal .NET thing. Managed profiler (ANTS) was not very useful.

Other affected methods:

- `MethodInfo.Invoke` (same behavior as `Activator.CreateInstance`)
- Invoking a compiled lambda expression
- Calling `new` operator on a generic argument type - becase `new T()` is compiled to `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()` - bummer.
- Dynamic method emitted with Reflection.Emit with `null` owner - see the `DynamicMethod` overload accepting the `owner` parameter.

We failed to solve this issue, but in our case replacing `Activator.CreateInstance` with a dynamically emitted constructor (with the owner type) solved our problem. It is a workaround, since the problem remains for other methods.

**EDIT 1**

BTW, we contacted Microsoft support on this issue, which turned out to be a complete waste of time. The best we could get from them is that this is how it is.

Comment: Interesting. Try profiling the code. If the usual .NET profilers are too high-level try perfview. That should hide nothing.

Comment: The results are most confusing and do not make much sense. PerfView was not good enough, we tried ANTS profiler. We are still digging it.

Comment: It seems to be an internal .NET thing - managed profiler is not very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would help: http://ayende.com/blog/3167/creating-objects-perf-implications

I would also try using the `ConstructorInfo` on its own instead of calling `Activator.CreateInstance` before wrapping it and emitting construction code (I don't remember if that's what `Activator.CreateInstance` do or not, still since it's part of the suggested solution I would have tried it before moving on).

Comment: The problem is not `Activator.CreateInstance` per se. The problem is that its performance degrades abruptly and drastically when an assembly with `NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy` is loaded. And it is not the only reflection related method that is affected. Now, we can replace `Activator.CreateInstance` with other things, but this is not the focus of the question. BTW, `new T` when `T` is a generic type is also affected, because `new T` is translated to `Activator.CreateInstance<T>` by the compiler.